# Docx to HTML poi java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, html, apache-poi, docx, nosuchmethoderror

I want to convert docx to html by poi. I am using following code

```
...
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(is);
  XHTMLOptions options = XHTMLOptions.create();
  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(htmlFile);
  XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
...
```

on the last line i got exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFHyperlinkRun.<init>(Lorg/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTHyperlink;Lorg/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTR;Lorg/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph;)V
```

I am using following libraries:

```
POI 3.10Final
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core 1.0.4.jar
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml 1.0.4.jar
```

Problem is that core and xhtml libraries are using POI of version 3.09, where there is constructor XWPFHyperlinkRun(CTHyperlink hyperlink, CTR run, XWPFParagraph p), but version 3.10 has constructor XWPFHyperlinkRun(CTHyperlink hyperlink, CTR run, IRunBody p).

I can not make downgrade of poi, because i am using functionality of 3.10 elsewhere, and core/xhtml libraries has not newer versions than 1.0.4. I tried to use docx4j library, but has some issues with it, but i would prefere if there would be an option to use poi instead of different library.

is there an option to solve this problem?

thanks for the answers

Comment: Apache POI doesn't provide any jars called things like `org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter` - where are those jars really coming from?

Comment: Not sure where the colleague found these (version 1.0.0 has been there before i tried to update them to version 1.0.4)
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/fr.opensagres.xdocreport/org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml

Comment: That's not part of Apache POI, that's some external group. You'll need to get in touch with them and ask them to produce a new version / download their source and recompile. 3.9 to 3.10/3.11 is source compatible, but a few bits (eg this) aren't binary compatible so you need to recompile

Answer (score 3):

Ok so 21.01.2015 new version of libraries has been created:

```
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core 1.0.5.jar
org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.xhtml 1.0.5.jar
```

which are compatible with version of

```
POI 3.10Final
```

and that solves this problem.

Comment: [Apache POI 3.11](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.11) came out about a month ago, so getting a version compatible with that would be better if you can!

Comment: Same solution for poi-ooxml 3.15 - so assume it would also work for 3.11

Answer (score 0):

As of right now there is no `org.apache.poi.xwpf.converter.core` or PDF compatible with POI 3.17 that I could find. You have to revert to xdocreport 2.0.1 and the non Apache classes `fr.sagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter`PdfOptions and these are compatible with the 3.17 POI suite.

I hope it will save someone the few hours it took me to figure this out.